# Convergence in law does not imply convergence in probability

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

It is well known that if $X_n \rightarrow^{p} X$ (i.e. convergence by probability) implies $X_n \rightarrow^{l} X$ (convergence by distribution).But the inverse in not true.Can anyone provide  a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = N(0,1)$ and $X_n = - X$.

then both $X$ and $X_n$ follows the same distribution. Hence we have $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$.

However, $$Pr(|X_n - X| > \epsilon)=Pr\left(|X| > \frac{\epsilon}2 \right)$$

which does not converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For any symmetric distribution $X$, indeed the distribution of $-X$ is the same as $X$, hence $X_n \xrightarrow{d} -X$, where $X_n = X$ for all $X$. However, clearly this convergence does not happen in probability in most cases.